# Get which entry of the list user clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, list, events

I'm making simple program in Air/Flex where layers of the image are listed in "list" Flex component. Idea is that the user can edit layers by dragging, clicking, double clicking etc. entries in the list.

However, it looks like I still don't grasp fully how event binding works in AS3 and Flex components. I tried to get program to trace the label of one entry in list when I double click it. It works for one entry in three, but others return reference error #1069. Below is relevant code in my layer class:

Declaring the layer panel and list:

```
<s:Panel x="10" y="29" width="276" height="261" id="newlevel" title="Background layers">
        <s:List  id="layers" x="10" y="41" width="254" height="143" dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true" dataProvider="{layerlist}"
                dropEnabled="true" dragComplete="layers_dragCompleteHandler(event)" doubleClickEnabled="true" doubleClick="layers_doubleClickHandler(event)" keyDown="layers_keyDownHandler(event)">

        </s:List>

        <s:Button x = "94" y = "192" width="86" height="26" label="OK" click="ok_clickHandler(event)" />
        <s:Label x="10" y="10" width="254" height="33" text="Click and drag to reorder, rename and delete layers"/>
    </s:Panel>
```

Script which defines "layerlist" and adds there some test values:

```
//list of layers in scene. Used in layer list for re-ordering and editing.
            public var layerlist:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
                [{label: "asd", price: "dsfdf"}]);
```

--

```
layerlist.addItem({label: "canoe", price: "dsfdf"});
        layerlist.addItem({label: "coyote", price: "dsfdf"});
```

And finally my event handler for double click:

```
protected function layers_doubleClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // user doubleclicked so rename this layer
            trace("doubleclick");
            trace(event.target.label);

        }
```

When user clicks one entry of the list, I need to know which entry it was from "layerlist". I thought that event.target would point to correct item but evidently it wasn't that easy. Before I made toolbar with buttons and used event.label to find out the button user pressed but it won't work in this situation.

What should I do?

Comment: Won't target reference the list and not the renderer?  Why not just look at 'layers.selectedItem' or 'layerlist[layers.selectedIndex]' ?

Comment: Thanks, that works too. Didn't know about selecteditem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target in event handler is always the child which initiates click from mouse. It can be Label, renderer, any child in the list container, depends on click point. 
You can do some workarounds, for example, analize event.target:

```
protected function layers_doubleClickHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var item:IItemRenderer;
    if (event.target is IItemRenderer)
        item = event.target as IItemRenderer;
    else if (event.target is Label)
        item = event.target.parent;

    trace(item.label);
}
```

Another way you can override itemRenderer class of list and listen double click from there.

Read about [event bubling in flash](http://www.senocular.com/?entry=286), it would help understand the picture.

Comment: Thanks, that explained a lot and I managed to get it work. Also, thanks for link.